# Running Linpack on Linux High performance computer

Tags: linux, performance, cpu, benchmarking

I am trying to do some benchmarks on Linux HPC machine which specs are as following

Total CPUs: 160 cores using latest 16C AMD Opteron Processors
Total main memory: 640 GB of 1600MHz
Total GPUs: 1024 cores (Tesla 2090 system)
Connectivity: 10GB Ethernet switch Hard disks: 1.8TB with 15k rpm (speed)

I have downloaded hpl from http://www.netlib.org/benchmark/hpl/ and tried to make the installation. however I am facing many issues such as sometimes one error occurs, sometimes another and it's so annoying because I have very little expertise in linux. I need a working guide for hpl if someone can do help me at this. The errors are as following

[jamal_MS@hpc Giki]$ mpirun -np 4 xhpl
[hpc:10439] *** Process received signal** 
[hpc:10440]  **Process received signal** 
[hpc:10440] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[hpc:10440] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[hpc:10440] Failing at address: 0x44000098
[hpc:10443]  **Process received signal** 
[hpc:10439] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[hpc:10439] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[hpc:10439] Failing at address: 0x44000098
[hpc:10444]  **Process received signal ***
[hpc:10444] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[hpc:10444] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[hpc:10444] Failing at address: 0x44000098
[hpc:10443] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[hpc:10443] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[hpc:10443] Failing at address: 0x44000098
[hpc:10439] [ 0] /lib64/libpthread.so.0() [0x39eae0f500]
[hpc:10439] [ 1] /opt/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so.1(MPI_Comm_rank+0x4e) [0x7fbbc6ab70c 
..
..
..

Thanks.

Comment: It might be useful if you could provide examples of what error messages you are seeing.

Comment: I have included the errors in question please if you can do some help